# docker nginx - 404 not found

Tags: docker, nginx

I followed these steps to setup `nginx` in `docker` at my server:

I create a `nginx/` folder and put all the `docker-compose.yml` and `conf.d/` with `conf.d/default.conf` accordingly.

`docker-compose.yml`:

```
version: "3.8"
services:
    web: 
        image: nginx:latest
        restart: always
        volumes:
            - ./public:/var/www/html
            - ./conf.d:/etc/nginx/conf.d
            - ./certbot/conf:/etc/nginx/ssl
            - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
        ports:
            - 80:80
            - 443:443

    certbot:
        image: certbot/certbot:latest
        command: certonly --webroot --webroot-path=/var/www/certbot --email abc@xyz.com --agree-tos --no-eff-email -d example.com -d www.example.com
        volumes:
            - ./certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
            - ./certbot/logs:/var/log/letsencrypt
            - ./certbot/data:/var/www/certbot
```

and my `cond.f/default.conf`:

```
server {
    listen [::]:80;
    listen 80;

    server_name example.com www.example.com;

    location ~ /.well-known/acme-challenge {
        allow all;
        root /var/www/certbot;
    }

    # redirect http to https www
    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name example.com;

    # SSL code
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }

    return 301 https://www.example.com$request_uri;
}

server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl http2;
    listen 443 ssl http2;

    server_name www.example.com;

    # SSL code
    ssl_certificate /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/nginx/ssl/live/example.com/privkey.pem;

    root /var/www/html/example/public;

    location / {
        index index.html;
    }
}
```

I am sure the `SSL` is working because I can access `https://example.com` with no problem.
But I always get 404 not found.
I do have a `public/` folder in `nginx/` folder with `index.html`. But somehow I always get 404.

I am using `Ubuntu 20`.

How can I resolve this?

Comment: Share your nginx config too

Comment: #1 If it is a simple html, you could use this validated nginx conf : https://gist.githubusercontent.com/jrichardsz/547c09a43a3c61b82c2d385af1de0e7c/raw/846e688730e4c3873604dde72c18315bc9bba2d4/docker%2520static%2520html.md #2 Try it with docker to validate if it is something in your compose file. #3 Just to validate, enter to your container `docker exec ...` and search the index.html

Comment: @Amin I updated with my config.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after @Amin's comments, I read carefully on my config file, and found out that with all the rerouting of the port 80 to port 443, the root folder actually change to `/var/www/html/example/public`. so I just have to change my `docker-compose` volume binding from:

```
volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html
```

to

```
volumes:
    - ./public:/var/www/html/example/public
```

Now it works.

Comment: Glad to hear that :)